# Adj.rand.index gives NaN values

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, nan, similarity

My dataset is way too big so I show a dummy example that also works for my question.

I want to compute the similarity between two cluster results. Furthermore, if I have four clusters (A,B,C,D) for each result, I want to check not only the overall similarity of result 1 and result 2 but also the individual cluster similarity (A1 vs A2, B1 vs B2...)

To do it, let's say now I want to compare cluster A between the two results. For it, I create a vector for each result where, if 1 appears, a data point has been clustered to A, and 0 if not.

```
c1 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0)
c2 <- c(0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0)
```

Then I used the rand.index function

```
rand.index(c1,c2)
adj.rand.index(c1,c2)
```

In this example, I get a rand.index of 0.46 and a adj.rand.index of NaN

if I change a bit c1 vector

```
c1 <- c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0)
c2 <- c(0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0)
```

The rand.index goes up to 0.53, and the adj.rand.index is 1.

Can somebody help me and explain why I get these weird results with adj.rand.index?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not advisible to use ones and zeros. If you look at adj.rand.index it generates zero by zero division for Case 1. Use ones & twos for cluster indexing, basically it is output of rclust function.

Comment: Yep, that solved the problem for the NaN results. Do you know why it yields a result of 1 in the adjusted rand index when the rand index is just 0.53?

Comment: You can copy source code of `adj.rand.index` and `rand.index` by typing without arguments and  play with it why it is happening in any given case (source is R code so no problem).